# Live search using lavarel and jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am new in here but I wanted to ask how I can set up a live search using laravel and jquery

See snippet below

```js
$('#inputSearch').on('keyup', function(){
$inputSearch = $(this).val();
if($inputSearch ==''){
  $('#searchResult').html('');
  $('#searchResult').hide();
}else{
  $.ajax({
method:"get",
url:"{{ route('search') }}",
data:JSON.stringify({
  inputSearch:$inputSearch
}),
headers:{
  'Accept':'application/json',
  'Content-Type':'application/json'
},
success:function(data){
  var searchResultAjax='';
  data = JSON.parse(data);
  console.log(data);
   $('#searchResult').hide();
  for(let i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    searchResultAjax+=`<p><a href="{{ route('display') }}">`+data[i].name+`</a> </p>`
  }
  $('#searchResult').html(searchResultAjax).show();
},
  })
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-5">
  <div class="search">
    <label for="" class="col-md-3">Search</label>
    <input type="search" class="form-control" id="inputSearch" name ="search" placeholder="Search...">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12" style="display: none;" id="searchResult">

</div>
```

Farmer controller

```php
    function display(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $farmers = Farmer::find($id);
        return view('crops.services', compact('farmers', $farmers));

    }

    function search(Request $request)
    {
        $inputSearch = $request['inputSearch'];

        $inputSearch = DB::table('farmers')
         ->where('name', 'like', '%'.$inputSearch.'%')
         ->orWhere('phone', 'like', '%'.$inputSearch.'%')
         ->orWhere('location', 'like', '%'.$inputSearch.'%')
         ->orWhere('idno', 'like', '%'.$inputSearch.'%')
         ->orWhere('coordinator', 'like', '%'.$inputSearch.'%')
         ->get();
         echo($inputSearch);
    }
```

web.php routes

```php
Route::get('search', [FarmerController::class, 'search'])->name('search');
Route::get('display', [FarmerController::class, 'display'])->name('display');
```

Comment: Are you experiencing errors here? What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Am having problem making it work, it displays the whole data except for the one searched for.

Comment: Instead of echo can you try `return $inputSearch`

Comment: Well upon reviewing the code, your function `search` should return the desired output.